# Java Jframe background assistance

Tags: java, jframe

Hello im trying to make a simple background split in half using a Jframe
How do i make the background move and adjust with my opened window.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Concert
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setSize(1000, 800);
      frame.setTitle("Concert!");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      Concertbackground component = new Concertbackground();
      frame.add(component);

      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Background: Ignore all the other imported things for now please.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;

/*
   component that draws the concert background
*/
public class Concertbackground extends JComponent
{  
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {  
      // Recover Graphics2D 
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

      //Background Top
      g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      Rectangle backgroundTop = new Rectangle (0, 0, 1000, 400); 
      g2.fill(backgroundTop);

      // Background bottom
      g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      Rectangle backgroundBottom = new Rectangle (0, 400, 1000, 800); 
      g2.fill(backgroundBottom);

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do i make the background move and adjust with my opened window.

Don't hardcode values. Use:

```
int width = getWidth();
int height = getHeight();
```

Then you can paint the top part the full width and the height from 0 to height / 2.

And the bottom part would be the full width with the height from height /2 to height.

Also, don't forget to set a layout manager for this component so you can add other components to it. Typically the main panel of the frame would use a BorderLayout.

Answer (score 0):

First, beware, that by default `JComponent` is transparent (this is very important for the next part).

Second, you should be calling `super.paintComponent` to ensure that the graphics context you are about to paint to has being prepared properly...

Thirdly, you shouldn't be relying on magic numbers...

For example...

```
public class Concertbackground extends JComponent
{  
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {  

        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Recover Graphics2D 
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        //Background Top
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Rectangle backgroundTop = new Rectangle (0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2); 
        g2.fill(backgroundTop);

        // Background bottom
        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        Rectangle backgroundBottom = new Rectangle (0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2); 
        g2.fill(backgroundBottom);

    }

}
```

If your intention is to use the component as the background of the frame, you should consider using `JFrame#setContentPane` instead of adding it to the frame...